# connect host localhost with guest localhost

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I am running a vm with ip `192.168.122.69` and I want to run a server that **must** run from host ip `10.0.2.2`. The server is running on port `8081` and I can connect to it at `192.168.122.69:8081` from the host.

The exact application is in developing a react app and sharing a react app server instance. However, I am mainly asking this as for educational purposes.. i.e. how do I make it so that connecting to `10.0.2.2:8081` is exactly the same as connecting to `192.168.122.69:8081` on the host or `127.0.0.1:8081` on the guest. I really just can not grasp how the routing, bridges, dns, whatever works so a thorough explanation would be very much appreciated.

I have done countless hours of research into this and while I'm sure I've gone over the answer several times, I haven't been able to grasp it.

Comment: More information is required about the host configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As far as making it so that, on the guestVM, connecting to `192.168.122.69:8081` is the same as connecting to `127.0.0.1:8001` just depends on the Web Server config. In the web server config files, publish the page on all IP addresses.

As far as port forwarding the address form host to guest, it really depends on your setup; most importantly what hypervisor you are using and what the host OS is.

Is it VMware? Then [this article answers your question](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2006955).